# asp.net (C#) custom login

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a custom login on a custom database. The database itself has username & password (name, address, ect). Now my problem is authorization. When I put in web.config `<authorization></authorization>` and run the program It won't load the masterpage design. So what's my alternative for authorization? And found some code for global.asax (for session):

```
void Application_OnPostRequestHandlerExecute()
{
    CheckLogin();
}

void CheckLogin()
{
    string Url = Request.RawUrl;
    int count = Url.Length - 10;
    string TestUrl = Url.Substring(count);
    string SessionData = Session["Authenticate"].ToString();
    if (SessionData == "" && TestUrl != "Home.aspx")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
    }
}
```

Can someone explain it a little? I mean the `testUrl`, why is the couter there `(url.lenght-10)?`

Comment: do you want to know how to authenticate a username/password on login page,and if they are correct redirect him to the default page/home.aspx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean Authentication or Authorization? These are different concepts.

The function you provided, just checks in a very strange way whether the page requested is the homepage or that the Session variable "Authenticate" is empty.

Are you using ASP.NET MVC? or plain ASP.NET?

I recommend you do a search on Google on the topic "Custom FormsAuthentication ASP.NET"